# Diagramm with varying sheets as data area's

Tags: libreoffice

I'm searching for a way to change the data area of a diagramm with a drop down menu:

on sheet1 i want to have the diagramm and a drop down menu where i can select from which sheet the diagramm take its data

so something like this:

```
$Sheet1.$A$1:$A$10
```

to this:
(pseudo code)

```
$VALUEOFF($B$1).$A$1:$A$10
```

where B1 is the cell where the drop down menu is located

(**discalmer:** I don't know if there is a command like `VLUEOFF()` )

in this drop down menu you can choose between the difrent sheets

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `INDIRECT()`, as in `INDIRECT("$" & "Sheet1" & ".$A$1")`.

In your example you would use `INDIRECT("$" & $B$1 & ".$A$1:$A$10")`.

Note that this LibreOffice feature is not portable to Microsoft Office's Excel owning to the way that the two suites reference sheets differently. Furthermore, because the `"..."` quoted parts are literal strings they do not adapt when (if) you insert/delete adjacent cells and their cell references move.